# Objective-C: Order an NSArray showing commas before spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have an NSArray:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *array = @[@"MacBook Pro, 13\"", @"MacBook, 12\"", @"MacBook Air, 11\""];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSLog(@"sortedArray: %@", sortedArray);

}

@end
```

If I sort the set alphabetically I get the following order:

- MacBook Air, 11"
- MacBook Pro, 13"
- MacBook, 12"

What I would expect is to see the following:

- MacBook, 12"
- MacBook Air, 11"
- MacBook Pro, 13"

How do I sort an NSArray to put commas before spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more elegant and robust solutions but quick and dirty you could simply ignore the comma when comparing the strings:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"MacBook Pro, 13\"", @"MacBook, 12\"", @"MacBook Air, 11\""];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    return [[(NSString *)obj1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "] compare:[(NSString *)obj2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "]];
}];
```

Result:

```
"MacBook, 12\"",
"MacBook Air, 11\"",
"MacBook Pro, 13\""
```

Comment: This seems to work on a small subset, but I'd have to test it across my data set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your situation, but I might suggest considering the comma as a "separator", meaning that you want to sort by everything up to the comma first, and only if they're the same, consider the portion of the string after the comma. This is very similar to your "sort comma before space" logic, but may handle edge cases a little better.

You can generalize this "comma as separator" logic to handle an arbitrary number of components like so:

```
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSArray <NSString *>*array1 = [obj1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray <NSString *>*array2 = [obj2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < array1.count; index++) {
        if (index >= array2.count) { return NSOrderedDescending; }

        NSString *string1 = [array1[index] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSString *string2 = [array2[index] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        NSComparisonResult result = [string1 compare:string2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch];
        if (result != NSOrderedSame) { return result; }
    }
    return array2.count > array1.count ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Note, I also assumed that that (a) you'd want case-insensitive sort; (b) you'd want to disregard extra spaces before or after the separators; and (c) you'd want to sort "9" before "11" (i.e. you wanted numeric sort).

Comment: This works for the example, but breaks on others.

NSArray *array = @[@"1,300 dogs", @"1 dog", @"1300 dogs"];

    "1,300 dogs",
    "1 dog",
    "1300 dogs"

Comment: @MichaelN - Obviously, but that wasn't the question you asked. The problem I was trying to solve was where the comma separated a "model" from some "configuration parameter", e.g., "iPad 2, 16GB", "iPad,128 GB", etc., where the comma was a way of separating models from some additional parameter. No simplistic "replace commas with spaces" or "remove commas" or "sort commas before spaces" sorts of approach is up to these sorts of examples. Now, if you want to sort those "dog" examples, where the comma serves no purpose other than thousands separator, that's a different question.

Answer (score -1):

What you basically want to do, is to sort the strings by its part up to the first `,`, which is a separator, not a part of the sort string.

So simply do, what you want to do:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:
^(NSString *left, NSString *right) 
{
  NSRange separatorRange;

  separatorRange [left rangeOfString:@","];
  if( separatorRange.length>0 )
  {
    left = [left substringToIndex:separatorRange.location];
  }

  separatorRange [right rangeOfString:@","];
  if( separatorRange.length>0 )
  {
    right = [right substringToIndex:separatorRange.location];
  }
  return [left compare:right];
}];
```

Typed in Safari.